# Is it possible to restrict indiscriminate access to file:// through Content Security Policy (CSP)

Tags: android, cordova, security, w3c, content-security-policy

I can restrict access to different sources through `Content-Security-Policy` in html. But for navigating through `file://`, it seems to allow files anywhere in the file system.

I tried using

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none'">`

When I load it using `file://path/to/myfile.html`, and use a `<a href="file:///var/log/system.log">System</a>`, I am able to click and see the contents of the system log.

My Question: Is it possible to restrict resource loading or navigation only to subfolders instead of everything on the file system for `file://` urls?

I tried on Google Chrome Version `71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)` MacOS 10.12.6.

**EDIT: Giving below real world case on Apache Cordova 8.1.2:**

Create new project using `cordova create HelloWorld`. Then edit `HelloWorld/www/index.html` and add `<div><a href="file:///etc/hosts">System</a></div>`.

Then do `cordova platform add android` and `cordova run android`. Tap on the `System` link and `/etc/hosts` can be viewed, even if I changed CSP to `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none'">` (at least on my unrooted mobile).

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't **hosted** your page, it is working in **href** but once you host it somewhere the actual URL of your site will start with **http:** or **https:** instead of **file:**. **And then Use CSP, it will by default block filesystem.**

When you open your locally created html, the browser just reads it as a file. Check the developer options in chrome and see the network tab, you will notice below:

1. There is no HTTP response because it is just read as file and
   not served by a server.
2. There is no HTTP response code, instead it will show as finished.
3. The HTTP response header tells the browser what to restrict and allow. (CSP should ideally be sent in the HTTP response and configured on the hosting server). The **meta** tag just acts like a fallback.

Try to host your site and then if your CSP restricts the source, you will see status code **403** or similar.

Hope this clears out your doubt.

Comment: Thank you.. but I don't have intention to host it. Specifically my question is about `file://`. There are use cases where such a thing is in use - not just for me. If it isn't possible, then thats it.. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible but not out of the box, please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/connect-src